# Is past perfect only to emphasize the contrast

Tags: past-perfect

"our money was running out but we'd had enough left to cover us for another week"

Does it mean, that first they noticed that they had money to cover them for another week then after they began spending more and more and the money was running out. I don't think so

I think this past perfect is only to emphasize the contrast between these two actions( running out and we had enough money for another week) . Our money was running out but we still had enough money for one week.

Comment: Your cited usage just looks ***invalid*** to me. I don't recognise any concept of Past Perfect being used to "emphasize the contrast" - either here or in any similar context where it might not be so obviously syntactically invalid.

Comment: so why past perfect in this case, I don't understand it

Comment: I would expect _but we had enough_ - unless the sentence comes from a longer passage written in the perfect tense. This could be because the writer is describing an incident earlier than their main narrative.

Comment: *Why?* Probably because the writer isn't very articulate. It's *remotely* possible the context could be one where Past Perfect "sorta" makes sense, as suggested by @KateBunting, but I think that's unlikely. From your point of view, the best thing is to simply ignore it as a mistake (and *don't* copy the usage yourself! :)

Comment: no it is not a flashback may be it is a mistake but it is in a book called "the last bandit a rock'n roll life" by Nikki Sudden

Comment: UNDERSTOOD in fact the money was running out but  we had had money for another week before our wallets were stolen